# How to handle this.props.location.satate null instances in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have a class component which accepts props. There are instances which props are not passed by the previous component. To handle it, I used a simple if condition `if(typeof(this.props.location.state) !== "undefined")`. As the requirements changes, now there are situations which `this.props.location.state` is not undefined but the parameter passed may be null (`this.props.location.state.params` can be null). I tried to handle it as follows

```
    componentDidMount() {
        if((typeof(this.props.location.state) !== "undefined") && (typeof(this.props.location.state.params) !== null)){

            this.setState({
                edit : true,
                noOfWorkingDays : this.props.location.state.params.noOfWorkingDays,
                arr_workingDays : this.props.location.state.params.arr_workingDays,
                workingHours : this.props.location.state.params.workingHours,
                workingMinutes : this.props.location.state.params.workingMinutes,
                timeSlot : this.props.location.state.params.timeSlot
            })
        }
        
    }
```

Now even though I pass the props, it doesn't go inside the if condition. And if props are not passed, instead of going to `else` part, it gives me this error `TypeError: Cannot read the property 'params' of null`. How can I handle these both situations without making any error? Thanks in advance

Comment: try `if(this.props.location.state&&this.props.location.state.params)`

Comment: Oh it worked! Thank you so much <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `if(this.props.location.state&&this.props.location.state.params)`

With just using `if(this.props.location.state)` it checks if `this.props.location.state` is truthy(not null and not undefined), same thing with `this.props.location.state.params`.

Answer (score 0):

Forget **typeof**. Try this code instead:

```
componentDidMount() {
    if(this.props.location.state && this.props.location.state.params !== null){
        this.setState({
        edit : true,
        noOfWorkingDays : this.props.location.state.params.noOfWorkingDays,
        arr_workingDays : this.props.location.state.params.arr_workingDays,
        workingHours : this.props.location.state.params.workingHours,
        workingMinutes : this.props.location.state.params.workingMinutes,
        timeSlot : this.props.location.state.params.timeSlot
        })
    }
}
```